# Not using anonymous function and having access to this and e

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to put the script inside an anonymous function in a separate function so that I can use it on various elements without duplicating the code.  The script needs to have access to both `this` and `e`.  `myID1` is using an anonymous function before trying to use a separate function.  `myID2` works, but I have a feeling isn't the preferred way.  `myID3` has access to `this`, but I couldn't figure out how to access `e`.  How is this done?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function otherFunction2(e,This){console.log(e,This);} 
        function otherFunction3(){console.log(this);} 
            $(function(){
                $('#myID1').on("click", "a.myClass", function(e){console.log(e,this);});
                $('#myID2').on("click", "a.myClass", function(e){otherFunction2(e,this);});
                $('#myID3').on("click", "a.myClass", otherFunction3); //Can't access e
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myID1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myClass">Click Me</a></div>
        <div id="myID2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myClass">Click Me</a></div>
        <div id="myID3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myClass">Click Me</a></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Avoiding anonymous functions is avoiding one of the most powerful features in this language.  Why would you want to avoid them?

Comment: I just don't want to duplicate the code.  Maybe I should use them, but just put a separate function inside the anonymous function (as I did under myID2 example)

Comment: @cdhowie Because such power comes with great responsibility. Closures are risky if you don't know how to clean up. They can junk up your entire memory.

Comment: @Derija93 They can, but why would you want to use a language without learning how to responsibly use its most important feature?

Comment: @cdhowie Not saying he shouldn't use those. I personally love them. But I also read a lot on how to use them and practiced a lot. I'd recommend he'd do the same. ;)

Comment: @Derija93 The nature of the question implies that the OP does not want to use anonymous functions.  My reply is only to indicate that anonymous functions are tremendously useful, and that one should not avoid them simply because one doesn't like them.  I am not trying to imply that there aren't cases when you need to be careful with them, only that one shouldn't try not to use them on some kind of principle or personal preference.

Comment: @cdhowie Well, yes. And my first response to you was one reason why one might consider not using anonymous functions. You asked, I answered... That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `otherFunction3()` to access `e`, simply declare `e` in the parameter list.  The parameter is passed by jQuery automatically, even if it's not declared:

```
function otherFunction3(e) { ... }
```

For `#myID2` you need to `.call()` the `otherFunction2`:

```
$('#myID2').on("click", "a.myClass", function(e) {
    otherFunction2.call(this, e);
});
```

at which point within `otherFunction2` the `this` variable will be set as usual, and you can remove the `This` parameter that you passed.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about call().  As Ian pointed out, e gets automatically passed, so now I have two solutions.  Any advantage for one over the other?

Comment: @user1032531 Personally, I wouldn't use your example with `#myID2` since all it does is call another function and pass the things that could be accessed in the first place anyways. Either use an anonymous function that does specific things for that selector, or create a single function that you can pass as a reference for several selectors. Don't forget, if you're trying to do the same thing to these 3 elements, you could've used: `$('#myID1, #myID2, #myID3').on("click", funcRef);`

Comment: I apply funcRef when loading the page, then do so if another element is dynamically added later.

Comment: @Ian I wouldn't use it either, it's just there to demonstrate how one _would_ call `otherFunction2` with the original parameters _if required_.  He might want to do something in the event handler, for example, and _then_ fall back to a more generic handler.

Comment: @Alnitak Oh I completely understand, I wasn't trying to undermine your answer...I think it's a great answer. But the OP asked for any advantage for one over the other, so I just gave me opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

The function (or function reference) passed to `on` gets called with one parameter: the `eventObject`. You can reference that however you want...`e` is fine.

Then, the value of `this`, which is implicitly defined (not a parameter), is automatically set as the element that the event was triggered for. So if you want to pass a reference, set up the reference like:

```
function someFunction(e) {
    console.log(e, this);
}
```

You only need to set the **one** parameter, and `this` is automatically defined properly.

If you want to call a different function from the event handler, like you do with `#myID2` and `someFunction2`, you can pass those explicitly (like you have), or use `call`.

References:

- `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- `on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/
- `call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Thanks Ian,  I think your solution works with '$('#myID3').on("click", "a.myClass", otherFunction3);'

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't allow method overloading. It uses a different approach: the *arguments* object that is available in each function scope. You can access provided parameters of the function through this object as if using an array. So you could use this:

```
function otherFunction3(){console.log(this, arguments[0])}
```

Also, regarding `otherFunction2`, it is a better approach to use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method which is a native method on all instances of the `Function` "class". Alternatively you can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). The difference being that `call` takes an infinite amount of parameters to be passed to your function while `apply` accepts only 2. The first in both cases will always be your `this` scope, all succeeding resemble your parameters. Apply will accept an array as second parameter containing all your parameters to pass to your function.

The code would look like this:

```
$('#myID2').on('click', 'a.myClass', function(e){otherFunction2.call(this, e);});
```

Respectively you would remove the `This` parameter and replace it with the lowercase "equivalent" in your `console.log` call. I trust this is actually needless to state...